# PHP GD unable to install JPEG

Tags: php, image, resize, jpeg, gd

Goal: Resize multiple images to 150x150px

Tried to install GD

`php -v:  PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2013 23:07:03)`

After install gd_info() showed

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 
    [T1Lib Support] => 
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

You can see JPEG support is FALSE. Then I tried compiling php with

```
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/ \
--enable-shared
```

Still nothing.. PHP error: `Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpg()`

Any ideas? Alternatives, imagemagick?

Comment: Are you sure it can find both jpeg lib and header files?

Comment: did you make clean before recompiling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167860/compiling-php-with-gd-and-libjpeg-support?rq=1  any of this stuff help?